# select * from (QQ) x not working where QQ is another select statements that runs on its own correctly

Tags: mysql, join

I was about to perform join on two select statements.

```
select x.A from (select blah - Q1 )x join (select blah - Q2 ) y on x.A = y.A
```

I have the query which is in the place of Q2:

```
select c.cust_id, c.card_id, c.name, s.name, sum(b.amt) - sum(p.amt) as DUE_AMT, DATEDIFF( now(), min(b.due_date)) AS DELAY
from cust c
inner join bill b on b.cust_id = c.cust_id 
left join payment p on p.bill_id = b.bill_id
inner join street s on s.street_id = c.street_id
where c.co_id=1
group by c.cust_id
```

This above statement runs OK and returns a resultset.

But when I try to enclose the above query within select * from (Q2) x, mysql workbench is not executing it. What am I doing wrong? Because select * from (Q1) x that is if I put other query it works perfectly.

```
select * from (
select c.cust_id, c.card_id, c.name, s.name, sum(b.amt) - sum(p.amt) as DUE_AMT, DATEDIFF( now(), min(b.due_date)) AS DELAY
from cust c
inner join bill b on b.cust_id = c.cust_id 
left join payment p on p.bill_id = b.bill_id
inner join street s on s.street_id = c.street_id
where c.co_id=1
group by c.cust_id
) x
```

Comment: "is not executing it" - isn't an issue description. Do you press an "execute" button?

Comment: @zerkms I press Ctrls+Enter in mysql workbench or click Query menu -> Execute current statement. Btw figured the problem out in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue myself. I am answering this question myself so developers like you won't unnecessarily waste time.

Its a bug in mysql workbench http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=67766 that was preventing the correct errors from being shown to the user.

So, for the record the problem was in my query there is this `c.name, s.name` in the select statement which produces data under the same column name in the result set. For normal query runs, its OK to have duplicate column names. However for querying the result set, duplicate column names are not allowed and it makes a lot of sense actually.